# Implementing HTML-minifier Plugin with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, minify

I'm looking for a way to minify my HTML code that's retrieved with Javascript like this

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
```

The HTML is very disorganized and poorly indented but its w3c validated. I came across this plugin https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier But need help implementing with raw JS/jQuery because it only provides instructions for node.js, and my app isn't server-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the file from [`dist` directory](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/tree/gh-pages/dist) in your page and use `minify` function. For reference [see the options](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference) and the [demo they provide](http://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/).

Below I implemented it into a quick demo that removes the attribute value quotes:

```js
$("#input").on("input", function() {
  $("#output").val(minify($(this).val(), {
    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
    collapseWhitespace: true
      // other options
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/html-minifier/50fad6e3a7a77f37671afae6782f557bd686bc8b/dist/htmlminifier.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Input</h1>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>

<h1>Output</h1>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: The demo you provided isn't actually minifying the code.

Comment: @Shabbb Supposing you define *minifying* collapsing whitespaces, add `collapseWhitespace: true` option. See edit.